# Kotlin delegation to expression instead of fixed reference

Tags: java, delegates, kotlin

Suppose I have a very intricate specification defined as an interface:

```
interface Spec {
    fun sayHello()
}
```

And a standard implementation:

```
class Impl(private val msg: String) : Spec {
    override fun sayHello() {
        println(msg)
    }
}
```

Now suppose that I want to create a class that implements this specification and delegates to an implementation, but the exact delegate object is mutable throughout the object's lifetime. Here's an example:

```
class Derived(var target: Spec) : Spec by target
```

The problem with the above example is that the constructor argument `target` is set as the delegate object when the constructor is called. The delegate is then accessed by the class directly instead of performing a property access. (This has been confirmed by looking through the bytecode produced by Kotlin.)

So, even if the property `target` is modified after the class is constructed, the delegate does not change.

Can anybody provide a method for performing this delegation in Kotlin without having to write out every single method?

An ideal solution would also allow for delegation to something as general as a lambda or other expression that would be evaluated and used as the delegate whenever the delegate is needed throughout the lifetime of the object.

Answer (score 6):

Right now there is no way to do that. See [Kotlin issue KT-5870](https://youtrack.jetbrains.com/issue/KT-5870)

> Currenlty Kotlin evaluates expression for delegate in class initializer

Answer (score 0):

You can add a level of indirection:

```
class Holder(var impl: Spec) : Spec {
    override fun sayHello() = impl.sayHello()    
}

class Derived(target: Spec, 
              private val holder: Holder = Holder(target)) : Spec by holder {

    fun changeTarget(newTarget: Spec) {
        holder.impl = newTarget
    }
}
```

Unfortunately `holder` must be a constructor parameter in order to be used with the delegation construct (as for Kotlin v1.0), so it complicates the primary constructor.

Comment: In this case you have to delegate all the methods manually what the author is trying to avoid.

Comment: @Michael yes it is true, however I only have to do the manual delegation only once for `Holder`, after that I can use it with no additional boilerplate

Comment: You don't need any additional classes for that. Just delegate everything right from `Derived`.

Comment: ye but I would have to manually delegate at `Derived2`, `Derived3`, etc. `Handle` keeps this all in one place

Comment: @voddan Only when he got multiple Derived. From what the author said, its not clear if he got Derived2/3/4

Comment: I believe all possibly usefull options are welcome here